# HTML_Table package only fills the header row

Tags: php, pear, html-table

I am baffled. The PEAR package [HTML_Table](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Table), which looks very simple, is only filling the contents of the header row of my tables. All the rows added with addRow are empty. Here's the code - any help appreciated!

```
require_once("HTML/Table.php");
$q = new HTML_Table();
$q->setAutoGrow(TRUE);
$th  = array("hdr1","hdr2","hdr3");
$tr1 = array("cell1","cell2","cell3");
$q->addRow($th, null, "th");
$q->addRow($tr1, null, "tr");
echo ($q->toHtml());
```

The result:

```
<table>
        <tr>
                <th>hdr1</th>
                <th>hdr2</th>
                <th>hdr3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show the php you using to show this output ?

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped `tr` in `addRow()` - it should be `td`.